# OIDC Github Actions with AWS Credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, openid-connect

Hello I am using this in my github actions

```
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
      role-session-name: "TerraformPlan"
```

and I am getting

Error: No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://myorg.com/__service/token

I created the role and provider in AWS..

Comment: Is the role a full ARN with account number? What parameters did you use to configure the provider?